# How to calculate $\mathbb{E}[Z_2(Z_2-\mu)^p)]$?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, covariance

> Consider $Z_1$and $Z_2$, two independent random variables that both follow the normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma ^2)$:
>
> $X = Z_2$
>
> $Y = Z_1 + Z_1(Z_2 - \mu)^p$ , where $p$ is a positive integer.
>
> Recall that if $X ∼ N(\mu, \sigma ^2)$, then:
>
> - $\mu_{2k}   = \mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^{2k}] = \frac{(2k)!}{2^kk!}\sigma^{2k} $
> - $\mu_{2k+1} = \mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^{2k+1}] = 0 $

I have to find the best linear predictor of $Y|X=x$ and therefore, I need to find $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$. After some manipulations when calculating $\mathbb{E}[XY]$, I end up dealing with this term $\mathbb{E}[Z_2(Z_2-\mu)^p)]$:

$\mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[Z_2(Z_1 + Z_1(Z_2 - \mu)^p)]$

$ = \mathbb{E}[Z_1Z_2] + \mathbb{E}[Z_1Z_2(Z_2 - \mu)^p]$ ;  $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent so $\mathbb{E}[Z_1Z_2] = \mathbb{E}[Z_1]\mathbb{E}[Z_2] = \mu^2$

$= \mu^2 + \mathbb{E}[Z_1]\mathbb{E}[Z_2(Z_2 - \mu)^p]$

$= \mu^2 + \mu \mathbb{E}[Z_2(Z_2 - \mu)^p]$

and I am not sure how to manipulate this to get what I want, am I missing something?

Comment: I told you under [your last post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4396225) how to get the formatting for operators like $\operatorname{Cov}$ right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E[Z_2(Z_2-\mu)^p]=E[(Z_2-\mu+\mu)(Z_2-\mu)^p]=E[(Z_2-\mu)^{p+1}]+\mu E[(Z_2-\mu)^{p}]$$